# Add UINavigationController to UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to load an UINavigationController inside an UIView (SideView) - do i need a ContainerView?

Ill tried with:

```
    let sideRoot = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sideRoot") as! SideRootViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sideRoot)
    sideView.addSubview(navController.view) // sideView is a UIView
```

But ill only see the NavigationBar, but no content.

Do i need an ContainerView? Or is it possible to add a (non fullscreen) UINavigationController?

Comment: Have you add a ViewController as root ViewController to this NavigationController.

Comment: Of course (see second line of code)

Comment: You must use ContainerView if you want to load another ViewController inside your current ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a NavigationController inside your ViewController's custom view, you must add the navigation controller to the view controller and add the view from the navigation controller into your custom view.

Try this code.

```
let sideRoot = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sideRoot") as! SideRootViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sideRoot)
self.addChildViewController(navController)
sideView.addSubview(navController.view)
```